# Does the number of useful comment votes add anything to reputation?

Tags: discussion, comments

I see a lot of people on Stack Overflow who have very high comment votes. Does that add up to their reputation score? If not, then how do those useful comment votes get justified?

Comment: What do you mean by "get justified"?

Comment: @Mat, I mean What's the use of it?

Comment: @Rahul The use of it is to help people. That is ultimately what the site is about. Writing a good comment helps directly. Upvoting a good comment calls attention to it and increases its weight in the thinking of other readers. "Reputation" is a side issue, of little to no real world importance.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, agreed and well said but you will also have to agree that earning reputation is one of the most attraction point in SO.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No. Comments and the votes on them have no effect on Reputation points.

The use of it is to bring comments other people find useful to the fore. When there are a lot of comments, the comment list will be "collapsed", hiding comments with no or low votes. Comments with a high number of votes are highlighted (the number of votes changes color and gets bolder).

There are also a couple of badges you can earn by leaving comments, one of which is based on number of votes.

Comment: But you do earn badges...

Comment: @rene, So to summarize; no reputation score change happens but you earn badges for same. make sense now.

Comment: Yes, you earn [Commentator](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/31/commentator) for leaving a comment and [Pundit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/56/pundit) if you left 10 comments with a score of 5 or more.

Comment: Ah.  Thanks for the info.  I was wondering why I have quite a few comment up votes but my reputation score doesn't move accordingly.

Comment: That said, gaining 1 reputation point for each upvote on a comment wouldn't have any real impact in your reputation but could encourage people to leave comments for "adjusting" an answer instead of writing a new, almost duplicated, answer.