# What should I do when the OP asks me to delete my answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Some time ago I answered a question. Today the OP asked me if I could please remove my answer so he could delete the question. I've read something similar here: [What to do when an OP asks to delete my code from my answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251923/what-to-do-when-an-op-asks-to-delete-my-code-from-my-answer). But this case is not about modifying the code, but completely removing the answer.

I guess he wants to remove it because of the downvotes.

What should I do? This is the question (image links to post):

[image]

Comment: Same answer: don't let someone pressure you into deleting an answer. Downvotes are not a valid reason to delete a question. He has asked a number of low-quality questions and probably starting to see a warning from the system. He thinks deleting his old downvoted questions will help the problem, but it won't. He's just digging himself a bigger hole. No reason to give him a shovel.

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you, should I send him to this question so that he understand why the answer will not be deleted?

Comment: Fun fact, you can't even delete your answer because he accepted it.

Comment: Downvotes are one reason my an asker might want to delete a question. Another is because of the possibility that it's an assignment which they're supposed to research and do, and they're fearful of their college finding out, or possibly of accusations of plagiarism. That has also been asked in recent months, and the answer was the same: don't delete. In fact, in the case where plagiarism was mentioned, a moderator went through and rolled back a whole bunch of their edits.

Comment: I think asking this question here has caused even more downvotes to the OP. Please don't downvote him more, regardless of his request to remove my answer, I think his question was totally valid.

Comment: My 2 cents: Just ignore such comments and move on

Comment: I have only 2k rep. Can anybody post an screenshot?

Comment: @algui91 agreed. I never downvote questions when I reach them through a link on meta. I think it would just be unfair.

Comment: @Michael Bad questions are bad questions.

Comment: @chrylis: true, but I don't think its fair if a question gets 50+ downvotes just because someone wrote about it on meta.

Comment: @rpax [here you go](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o6yt0.png)

Comment: @user000001 Thank you!

Comment: Deleting a question because you recognized it was bad and you dont want to bother others is also a possibility. But in this specific case I guess since the answer is rather helpfull deleting the question is not needed, anyway.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

#### Nothing!

Your answer is not only for the OP, but also for everyone else in the community who happen to have the same question in the future.

Just because the OP wants to delete his question, is no reason to remove your answer.

Comment: @algui91 That's totally up to you. There is no reputation on meta anyway, so there is no difference.

Comment: *(To be honest, I was expecting you to ask me to delete my answer, for the sake of irony)*

Comment: But what if OP himself delete his question ... answer being a child item anyways will be deleted and will cause loss of reputation right? this has happened with me as well (multiple times) ... only difference is ... OP didn't even bothered to let me know why in earth he his deleting the question.

Comment: @Rahul You can't delete questions in certain cases - see the [how does deleting work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) answer.

Comment: But the community decided (by closing *and* downvoting) that the question is not useful. So why keep it?

Comment: @thegrinner, OP can delete the post (I mean question) without any restriction; even if it has a accepted answer. I know it very well, cause experienced it.

Comment: @rahul Nope. Not if it has an upvoted or accepted answer. Try deleting this one for example: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251387/does-the-number-of-useful-comment-votes-add-anything-to-reputation Your answer was probably deleted by the community deleting the question, not the OP.

Comment: @user000001, that's true but you are not considering the test case where upvote+acceptance given by the OP only. He can remove +1 -> acceptance -> then delete :)

Comment: @svick Well the community (at least 13 people) also decided that the answer is useful, and upvoted it. Doesn't that count in your opinion?

Comment: @user000001 Well, it seems like it does not matter how many people upvoted it, because now the question is removed ;-).