# Question poster has asked me to remove my answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Someone who asked a question on Stack Overflow a few months ago (and has gotten five downvotes for it at the time of this writing) is now asking me to delete my answer because he wants to remove his question. My questions here are:

1. Why is he asking this? Can't he delete his question without me removing my answer?
2. Is it correct/ethical/inline with Stack Overflow standards to fulfill such a request? I have spent time writing a good answer to a bad question and have got upvotes for it. What do you folks suggest?

Comment: OPs aren't allowed to delete their question if the post has an answer.

Comment: I would suggest you no-sell that request -- it is abusive. @Sam, IIRC it has to be an upvoted answer (tally > 0).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Right, I did think there was a clause somewhere.

Comment: Ignore the request, you invested time answering.

Comment: Some people ask homework questions, get their answers, and then want to erase their tracks...

Comment: If the answers are good don't delete them. If the OP vandalises flag and we'll take action. I'm strongly against this selfish revisionist attitude of some users.

Comment: There's [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258745/what-should-i-do-when-op-ask-me-to-delete-my-answer) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251923/what-to-do-when-an-op-asks-to-delete-my-code-from-my-answer) that deal with similar situations, if you're interested.

Comment: If the answers are good but the question is bad, try editing the question.  If the question can't be saved but the answer could apply to a good question, you could ask your own question to have a place to put the answer.

Comment: You could tell the OP that deleting his/her question will not remove the downvotes from their invisible reputation. They'll get the rep points back, but if they have too many downvotes (whether on live or deleted questions) they can still be banned. He/she would be better improving the question, even if it is an old one.

Comment: @joe though based off the description here sounds like the questioner may just want to remove the heavily downvoted blot on their question history.

Comment: Only 183 Reversal badges have been awarded according to the site. If your answer makes it to +20 that's a pretty rare badge earned. It might be proper to consider the weighty issues here and scorn badges, but... they're there.

Comment: I think the OP is actually trying to rage-quit, rather than get around the question ban. See [the OP's recent comment history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2501518/mohammad-reza-tayyebi?tab=activity).

Comment: Same thing happened here: [What should I do when OP ask me to delete my answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258745/)

Comment: I had this as well. OP asked a question, I answered it and it even got upvoted. Then OP thought his question (despite the answer) wasn't clear enough, so he rewrote it and posted it as a different question. Although it's good that OP wanted his question to be of good quality, it really bugged me that he did it this way. Not necessarily because of the points, but because of the work I put into the answer. I also am very annoyed when I write an answer, and the question turns out to be deleted before I can answer it.

Comment: B.t.w. eventually I removed my answer because, well, the question was a duplicate now and the new version had attracted right answers in the mean time as well, so I made this exception in favor of the 'better' version of the question. But I was very reluctant in doing so, and in another situation I might just have kept it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. Taken from the [faq page about deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that):

   > ### When *can't* I delete my own post?
   >
   > You can't delete *answers* that have been accepted.
   >   You can't delete any *question* that:
   >
   > > - has an upvoted answer, or
   > > - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)
2. Actually strictly speaking, it's not your call to make. By posting your answer, you contributed something positive, helpful to other people around the world (upvotes are the indicator). So removing it will remove something useful, hence against the "spirit" of Stack Overflow.

That said, if you really believe the question itself got no real value you can delete your answer and let the OP delete his question. The rules are not black and white, and got more than 50 shades of gray.