# SO etiquette - should answer be removed on OP request to improve visibilty

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, etiquette

Is it common for users to ask to remove answers to *not distract other people from answering the question* when answer does not satisfy poster? If it is, what is typical / established response?

I checked

- [When or should you delete your incorrect answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37738)
- [What should I do when OP ask me to delete my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258745)

and few similar questions but it doesn't apply here in my opinion.

Pro:

- it could be a valid  argument - is question with answer less likely to get more answers?

Against:

- shouldn't bounties be used to improve visibility?
- if it does not solve the problem others will not waste time to repeat it.

Comment: *Is it common for users to ask to remove answers?* No, it isn't. *But it doesn't apply here in my opinion.* What is *here* exactly? Please provide a link, Meta effect be damned.

Comment: I think the actual thing that OP asks is not to improve visibility, but to remove incorrect answer, so that others with correct answer do not need to read this other incorrect answer and the explanation why it's incorrect from OP in the comments, in order to answer themselves, therefore increasing chance for OP to get correct answer.

Comment: What kind of logic is that? Why would the existence of an incorrect answer *discourage* someone from providing what they feel is the correct answer? Has no one heard of [Cunningham's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward_Cunningham)? (As this comment demonstrates.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My thoughts:

#### Yes

- a question with more answers is less likely to attract people who may add an answer.
- bounties should be used to attract more attention, better answers, etc.

#### No

- you shouldn't delete an answer for the reasons you mentioned because:

  - using the voting system provides feedback on irrelevant answers and gives visual indicators when viewing answers on a question, while it does *not* encourage people to look at a question from the grid when they see it already has *n* answers.
  - everyone is entitled to contribute their two cents on a question (the caveat being the above point).
  - if they're really not relevant, they could be flagged for deletion.

A possibly important point to note would be that if a question is attracting answers that do not answer the question as the OP intended, the question should probably be made more specific so there is no room for misunderstanding.