# Is Stack Overflow about programming Q&A or IT Q&A?

Tags: discussion, scope

I thought that Stack Overflow is for programmers and about programming. But now I see there a lot of questions about system administration and even about using Excel formulas. Could anyone explain what questions can be posted on Stack Overflow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (note that having rules does not stop people from posting off-topic questions, and we cannot get around to closing them all)

Comment: You know how even in a country that has laws, people break those laws and sometimes get away with it? Same thing here.

Comment: I'd also say that coding with Excel is still coding. Functional, reactive coding, at that. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0yKf8TrLUOw for example.

Comment: Excel is absolutely a programming tool. I'm sorry it's more pedestrian than Java, but it is a readily available tool many people have and questions on how to make it do things for you are absolutely on topic here.

Comment: About deleting answers: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258746/4751173

Comment: The VBA code underpinning excel is a fully turing complete programming language

Answer (score 6):

The general rules about what's on-topic here and what not can be found in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). More details can be found on Meta, in questions tagged [scope](/questions/tagged/scope).

If you see a question about system administration, flag it:

[image: belongs on Server Fault]

If you see a *basic* question about Excel, flag it:

[image: belongs on Super User]

<sub>(note that some advanced Excel questions, e.g. those involving VBA and *complex* formulas, are on-topic, see the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/excel/info))</sub>

That way, you'll help to enforce the rules. You can also hop into the [SOCVR chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to ask if a question is really off-topic and get help with closing the question, but be sure to read [their FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq) first.

Comment: It is not only closing what we do. We can also guide users when they have doubt if closing is needed and/or fir which reason. We try to be more then just a close vote mob ....

Comment: @rene sure. 'Help with' is not just a close vote 'megaphone'. I've edited the answer a bit.

Comment: @Pavel_K downvotes on Meta don't cost reputation and don't lead to question bans (well, only in rare cases). I think it's a useful question to have around; the downvotes may be because of lack of research (one trip to the help center would probably suffice to answer the question).

Comment: Upvotes on Meta don't give reputation either, so I'm not keeping it for the reputation. I'm keeping it for future users who might have the same question as you did.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, Stack Overflow is *only* for programming questions. General IT questions have their own sites, so if people want to ask about that they should go to Super User or Server Fault.

The close vote queue often contains 10K to 20K questions, so we can't actually close all of the off-topic questions. This is especially the case for smaller tags that people with enough reputation to vote to close don't visit much. That's why we'll periodically have to have wide-spread cleanup efforts in certain tags; there are certain tags, such as [openvpn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openvpn), that consisted almost entirely of off-topic questions at one point, and there are *still* plenty of tags like that around. Off-topic and low-quality questions are less likely to survive in higher-traffic tags, but it does still sometimes happen.

That being said, the fact that off-topic questions sometimes slip through the cracks isn't evidence that they are, in fact, on topic. If you see examples of these, I'd definitely encourage you to flag them as off-topic and/or mention them in the Stack Overflow Close Vote chat room.

It's also worth noting that there have been numerous discussions on whether Excel formula and macros are on-topic in the past on Meta. As some people have indicated in the comments, these are (arguably) still programming questions, which means that they're on-topic.