# How should I respond to a request to delete my answer to a bad question?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, low-quality-posts, upvotes

I am not sure how (or if) I should respond to the question in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39920197/can-mendeley-work-without-downloading/39920666?noredirect=1#comment79260025_39920666).

I answered a question, and it got an upvote and was then marked as the correct answer; but the question has received several downvotes, and the OP is seemingly now concerned about his reputation (despite being a 30K+ user). He has asked me to upvote the question or delete my answer.

Certainly I am not going to be pressured into upvoting the question. But if my answer is stopping him deleting a bad question, should I delete the answer? I'm inclined to say no, but I haven't been put in this position before.

Comment: _"OP is seemingly now concerned about his reputation"_, or maybe the OP realized the question wasn't that great. Either way, the question is closed now, and on it's way to deletion.

Comment: @Cerbrus that's what I thought at first, but he asked me to upvote the question, which would be odd if he knew it wasn't great and just wanted to improve the site by deleting it.

Comment: That's also a possibility, indeed.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258745/what-should-i-do-when-the-op-asks-me-to-delete-my-answer/258746#258746

Comment: Follow your inclination. Say no, unless you agree that your answer is completely worthless and should be deleted. If the user wants to pursue it, they can ask a moderator to get involved. Don't let anyone badger you into doing things on this site.